# Can't get inline icon to show up in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a pretty simple Chrome extension to supplement a web page. One of the features is to add links to watch relevant matches on the internet. The relevant HTML is here:

```
<div class="option-wrap">
    <a class="option" href="http://www.google.com" target=_blank>
        <div class="option-icon tv-icon"></div>
        TV Link
    </a>
</div>
```

With my CSS here:

```
.tv-icon {
    margin-right: 2px;
    float: left;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-image: url("http://sayeedanwar.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tv-servizi.png") no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You'll see that several classes appear in the HTML that aren't in my CSS; they are from the web page as it exists. The goal of this code is to get the television icon specified by the URL to appear inline to the right of the text "TV Link". When I run the code, it seems like there is space allocated for the icon, and the cursor is able to click on this space, but there is no visible icon. Is there something wrong with my CSS< or is this a function of the existing webpage code that I'll have to find a workaround for?

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3Rqv/1/) with the mentioned code.

Comment: Your syntax for the `background-image` rule is incorrect; it looks like a cross between the that and the shorthand background rule. The image you're linking to is much larger than the space you've afforded it. Finally, your HTML in invalid. Links can't contain divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.tv-icon {
    margin-right: 2px;
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-image: url("http://sayeedanwar.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tv-servizi.png");
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JZTPk/)

changes I made:

- remove 'no-repeat' in 'background-image'
- add 'background-size' and 'background-repeat'

I also changed the size. Change it back if you want.

Comment: works thank you, i'll accept when i can. what does 'cover' mean?

Comment: It basically means to 'resize the image so that it covers the whole element, both by width and height'.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the last two lines of your css to this

```
background-image: url("http://sayeedanwar.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tv-servizi.png");
background-size: cover;
```

@Richard Rodriguez - You shouldn't need `no-repeat` if you have `background-size: cover`.
Since cover will encompass said area and reduce the opportunity for repeats to null.